# Why is killing an Console.Clear() in a .NET Application my LabView call?

Tags: .net, exception, labview

I got a strange behavior in my Labview 8.2 program. I wrote a console application in C# because this horrible old labview is not capable of .NET DLLs.

However - I have a Console.Clear() command in my application that should clear the screen. This works in standalone perfectly.

But if I try to open my exe from within labview using the exec sys command vi, it will crash with an unmanaged handler. The exception is thrown by the CLI.

What the heck does labview do here? Why is it not simply showing the command promt starting the application but doing something not understandable and crashing?

Does this mean I cannot open ANY command line tool that's using Console.Clear() within it source code?

**Exception + Stack Trace**

```
Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
    at System.Console.Clear()
    at TestApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\xxx\TestApp\Program.cs:Zeile 14.
```

[image: Labview code]

Comment: Can you post your LabView code?

Comment: Also can you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: This is entirely expected when you use the VI block this way.  When you redirect output then LabView executes the program with the equivalent of ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true.  A highly logical choice since there won't be anything to look at anyway.  There will be no console window, trying to clear the non-existing window will bomb.  Just stop shooting your foot and you won't have a problem, delete Console.Clear().

Comment: Well this is a solution that will work for me (hmmm already waiting for the CreateWindow-Call I didn't reach so far. Suppose this will be the next mess)... But - to come back 2 topic - what is with the whole bunch of applications using console.clear() I can not recompile? Simply throw away? Or how can the labview part be modified to get compatibility with established standards since Windows 95?

Comment: @AllDayPiano If you remove the Console.Clear() line does the application run as expected? Does a console window appear? If no console window appears then why do you want to clear it?

Comment: I want to clear it, because this is a standalone-application that should be called from labview. I cannot throw my whole concept into the trash bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the Console.Clear() in your code but want it to work in a system where no console window is displayed then you will need to determine if the console has been displayed.

```
var output = Console.OpenStandardInput();

if (output != System.IO.Stream.Null)
    Console.Clear();
```

Comment: Well ok. Sounds plausible. But is there only an issue with Console.Clear() or do I have to expect more issues with CreateWindows-Calls?

Comment: The program should run as normal for everything else. So you will only encounter problems where you try and interact with a console which doesnt exist.

Comment: Hmm ok this will help for me, but what can I do with all the other applications that don't give a f*** if a tiny little program called labview will mess up all programs that were not specially designed for NI?

Comment: If you have a program which you need to display the console then you can write your own wrapper program which launches the second program with the console window.

Comment: Hmm ok. Then I'll have to do this :-(

Comment: You could tell LabVIEW to run cmd.exe instead if you want a console. Then run a command in that console. LabVIEW is doing exactly what you asked it to. Ask it to do something else.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.isoutputredirected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Yes thats a better option assuming hes using 4.5 or above.

Comment: @srm that should be an answer, as the OP says they have applications they can't rebuild. AllDayPiano, calm down a bit!

Comment: @nekomatic: Haha that's easy to say :) Labview just cost me a whole day of installation becaused it messed up sth with some librarys. I don't know if the developers of LV have already recognized, that we got the year 2016! But you're right - it's not worth it.

Comment: Didn't you say you're using LabVIEW 8.2? That was released in 2006. Who needs to get up to date here? :-P

Comment: @nekomatic Haha brilliant. :)

Answer (score 2):

LabVIEW is doing exactly what you asked it to by not having a command shell. Ask it to do something else to get what you want. Try telling LabVIEW to run cmd.exe instead if you want a console. Then run a command in that console (use the /C option to do so). See picture... replace  with the command you want to run.

[image]